# Any DS3231 RTC C++ experts here?

Tags: pi-3, c++

I'm trying to program a DS3231 using a translated
C++ Arduino Mega 2560 library. Translated means all the
Arduino I2C methods have been changed over to use the
BCM2835 GPIO/SPI/[I2C] library.

The RTC will not be used as a hw clock with the Pi 3B.

Two very basic methods are available:

```
void setDateTime(uint16_t year, uint8_t month, uint8_t day, uint8_t hour, uint8_t minute, uint8_t second);
RTCDateTime getDateTime(void);
```

where `RTCDateTime` is a structure containing the year month day hour minute second.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Initialize BCM2835 library and I2C interface.
    //
    if (! bcm2835_init()) {
        cerr << "BCM2835 Library initialization failed. Exiting." << endl;
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (! bcm2835_i2c_begin()) {
        cerr << "I2C: 2. I2C initialization failed. Exiting." << endl;
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    RTCDateTime dt; 
    DS3231 clock;

    clock.begin();
    clock.setDateTime(2019, 2, 18, 9, 30, 0);
    dt = clock.getDateTime();

    cerr << "Raw data: " << endl
         << "Year:   " << (unsigned)dt.year   << endl
         << "Month:  " << (unsigned)dt.month  << endl
         << "Day:    " << (unsigned)dt.day    << endl
         << "Hour:   " << (unsigned)dt.hour   << endl
         << "Minute: " << (unsigned)dt.minute << endl
         << "Second: " << (unsigned)dt.second << endl;

    // Clean up and terminate
    //
    bcm2835_i2c_end();
    bcm2835_close();
    cerr << "T~e~r~m~i~n~a~t~e~d" << endl;
} // End main()
```

When I run the program, I constantly get the same result each time it's executed:

```
user1@rpi3b2:~/projects/bcm2835/DS3231_02$ sudo ./main
Raw data: 
Year:   2000
Month:  0
Day:    30
Hour:   9
Minute: 0
Second: 19
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
It would seem the DS3231 RTC is not accepting the new date/time I
re-program it with.

Methods used:

// Set battery type and default date/time.
//
bool DS3231::begin(void) {
    setBattery(true, false);
    t.year = 2000;
    t.month = 1;
    t.day = 1;
    t.hour = 0;
    t.minute = 0;
    t.second = 0;
    t.dayOfWeek = 6;
    t.unixtime = 946681200;

    return true;
}

// Set the RTC's date/time settings.
//
void DS3231::setDateTime(uint16_t year, uint8_t month, uint8_t day, uint8_t hour, uint8_t minute, uint8_t second) {
    I2C_writeByte(0x00, dec2bcd(second));
    I2C_writeByte(0x01, dec2bcd(minute));
    I2C_writeByte(0x02, dec2bcd(hour));
    I2C_writeByte(0x03, dec2bcd(dow(year, month, day)));
    I2C_writeByte(0x04, dec2bcd(day));
    I2C_writeByte(0x05, dec2bcd(month));
    I2C_writeByte(0x06, dec2bcd(year-2000));
}

// Read the RTC current date/time.date/time 
//
RTCDateTime DS3231::getDateTime(void) {
    int values[7];

    for (int reg = 0x06; reg >= 0x00; reg--) {
            values[reg] = bcd2dec(I2C_readByte(reg)); 
    }   

    t.year      = values[0] + 2000;
    t.month     = values[1];
    t.day       = values[2];
    t.dayOfWeek = values[3];
    t.hour      = values[4];
    t.minute    = values[5];
    t.second    = values[6];
    t.unixtime  = unixtime();

    return t;
}

// Convert a decimal value to a BCD format.
//
uint8_t DS3231::dec2bcd(uint8_t dec) {
    return ((dec / 10) * 16) + (dec % 10);
}

// Convert a BCD value to a decimal format.
//
uint8_t DS3231::bcd2dec(uint8_t bcd) {
    return ((bcd / 16) * 10) + (bcd % 16);
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// I2C read/write wrapper methods for the BCM2835 library.
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Read a device  8-bit register contents.
//
char DS3231::I2C_readByte(char reg) {
    char buf[] = {reg};
    bcm2835_i2c_read_register_rs(buf, buf, 1);
    return buf[0];
}

// Read a device 16-bit register contents.
//
unsigned short DS3231::I2C_readU16(char reg) {
    char buf[] = {reg, 0};
    bcm2835_i2c_read_register_rs(buf, buf, 2);
    int value =  buf[0]*0x100+buf[1];
    return value;
}

// Read a device 16-bit register contents.
//
short DS3231::I2C_readS16(char reg) {
    int result;
    result = I2C_readU16(reg);
    if (result > 32767)result -= 65536;
    return (short)result;
}

// Write a device 8-bit register.
//
void DS3231::I2C_writeByte(char reg, char val) {
    char buf[] = {reg, val};
    bcm2835_i2c_write(buf, 2);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in Linux kernel driver? You can easily activate that with ```dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231``` in /boot/config.txt. That's got to be easier than hacking some Arduino code

Comment: Go through below links, might be helpful to you. https://os.mbed.com/users/brianclaus/code/ds3231/file/b87f3e7258bb/ds3231.cpp/
https://os.mbed.com/users/techstep/code/DS3231/file/1607610a4ee9/DS3231.cpp/ Regards,
Surendra Allam.